# Reference for Wiener's formula in the context of Fourier

Tags: fourier-analysis

Could anyone point me to an easily available reference for Wiener's formula used in the following answer ?

[fourier transform of radon measure](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/38308/fourier-transform-of-radon-measure)

I tried the most obvious sources without success.

Comment: Isn't this just the Plancherel formula for measures? Perhaps you'll find the Tauberian theorem(s) relevant.

Comment: @Steve Huntsman: No. But it follows from a simple calculation, starting with the RHS.

Answer (score 1):

It is a formula usually attributed to Parseval:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsevals_theorem

Answer (score 0):

You can find a proof of this in

W. F. Eberlein, "A note on Fourier-Stiltjes Transforms", Proceedings of the AMS, Vol 6, No 2, April 1955, pp 310-312.

I think the result is older than this paper.